# Android gradient/layer list with large center color

Tags: android, gradient, layer-list

I am trying to achieve a general background to my activities that I would like to be understated, so I've settled on a small amount of purple in one corner, and a small amount of green in another corner with a very large band of white between them.

I cannot see how to set center color width, so have tried using a layer list to the following effect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="20dp"
            android:height="20dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="15dp" android:right="15dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="1dp"
            android:height="1dp"/>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#00000000"
            android:centerColor="#00000000"
            android:endColor="#92ff16"
            android:angle="135"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="15dp" android:left="15dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="1dp"
            android:height="1dp"/>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#ff1692"
            android:centerColor="#00000000"
            android:endColor="#00000000"
            android:angle="135"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

This looks fine in the Android Studio designer but in the app the colored squares overlap, even though theiur dp-figures are very small.

Is there a simple method to space apart the corner shapes?